# Import Python file which contains pySpark functions into Django app

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to import in views.py of my Django app, a python file "load_model.py" which contains my custom pyspark API but I got an error And I can't figure out how to solve it.

I import the file "load-model.py" with a simple:

```py
import load_model as lm
```

My load_model.py contains the following code (this is just part of the code):

```py
import findspark
# findspark.init('/home/student/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7')
findspark.init('/Users/fabiomagarelli/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7')


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressionModel
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.sql import Row
from collections import OrderedDict


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('RForest_Regression').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
model = RandomForestRegressionModel.load('model/')

def predict(df):
    predictions = model.transform(df)
    return int(predictions.select('prediction').collect()[0].prediction)

# etc... ... ...
```

when I lunch `python manage.py run server` on my command line, I get this error log:

```
19/07/20 07:22:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 585, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 570, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 288, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 294, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 334, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 350, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 101, in iter_all_python_module_files
    modules_view = sorted(list(sys.modules.items()), key=lambda i: i[0])
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
Exception ignored in: <function JavaWrapper.__del__ at 0x11d2de6a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 41, in __del__
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 2000, in detach
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1298, in _detach
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 628, in _garbage_collect_object
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1370, in debug
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1626, in isEnabledFor
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception ignored in: <function GatewayConnection.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x11da84d90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1061, in <lambda>
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 640, in _garbage_collect_connection
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 487, in quiet_shutdown
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1370, in debug
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1626, in isEnabledFor
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

pySpark is installed on my computer, I was using it on my jupyter notebook for fitting the model so I don't think the problem is that pyspark is not installed. Any suggestions?

Comment: no one have deployed a ML model with pyspark on a Django app? .-.

Answer (score 0):

So I found some tutorials on how to deploy a pySpark ML model using databricks, tensor flow etc. All too complex solutions for my limited pySpark knowledge and a project deadline in 4 weeks.

However, I found a workaround which consists in "deploying" the ML model on a Flask App then call it from my Django App (my project app). I think this may be very useful for someone facing my same problem. Not the best practice maybe but working! That's why I'm going to explain each step:

**1. Create a Flask Application**

- in the command line (in your virtual env if you have one), type: `pip install flask`.
- make a new folder (i call it 'static') and place in it the `model` folder which is obtained by saving the pySpark model (it contains other folders: data, metadata...)
- create a new folder for your flask app (can be in the parent folder of your django app) and create a file in it named `main.py` (you can use whatever name but for the code I'm gonna post, this is the name I used).
- in `main.py`, copy paste this:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/student/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7')

# various pySpark imports here...

app = Flask(__name__)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('RForest_Regression').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
# I'm using a RandomForest ML model, change it as appropriate
model = RandomForestRegressionModel.load('static/model/')

# define here all your functions to make a prediction (eventual arguments cleaning...)

@app.route('/predict')
# this is the function called when the page: '127.0.0.1/5000/predict' is requested.
# you can pass arguments in here by calling: '127.0.0.1/5000/predict?data=...'
numbers = request.args.get('data') # numbers = '...'
makePredictions(numbers)

def makePredictions(n):
    # your function here
```

- now on the django app, open `views.py`
- add the fucntion to request the predictions from the flask app:

```py
# Send a request to the flask App where the model is hosted
def getPredictions(request):
    try:
        data_to_predict = request.GET['data']
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict?data=%s' % data_to_predict
        response = get(url)
        return JsonResponse(response.text, safe=False)
    except:
        print('ERROR getPredictions: no pySpark module or Flask App not running or wrong arguments')
```

- then call the `getPredictions` function from javascript in your django app (I haven't done it yet so I don't have a snippet but so far is working, I tested it passing custom arguments).

You have to remember to run the flask app and the django app together in order to make it works:

- `cd` into your Flask app folder (where you have the `main.py` file) then type: `export FLASK_APP=main.py` and `flask run`
- then `cd` into your django app (where you have the `manage.py` file) then type: `python manage.py runserver`

I hope this will be useful to someone and that my explaination is not too messy. I will appreciate any comments, suggestions and requests. :)